# Did Abraham pass or fail in God's test?

Tags: genesis, abraham

The story about Abraham sacrificing Isaac: **Gen 21:12**

> But God said to him, “Do not be so distressed about the boy and your
>   slave woman. Listen to whatever Sarah tells you, because it is through
>   Isaac that your offspring will be reckoned.

and later: **Gen 22:2**

> Then God said, “Take your son, your only son, whom you love—Isaac—and
>   go to the region of Moriah. Sacrifice him there as a burnt offering on
>   a mountain I will show you.”

Abraham used to dispute with God previously (**Gen 18:23**). If he listened, shouldn't he answer something like *"And what about his offsprings, huh?"*

Couldn't be the point something like *Do you remember what I told you?* It is hard to believe that the message is *Be fanatic*. The **Gen 22:12** could be a polite way how to say *Stop it, fool!*

I'd like to know if there is some inconsistency in this explanation and consequently: if Abraham *passed* or *fail* his test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hebrews 11 explains that this was a test of faith: (KJV)

> 17 By faith Abraham, when he was tried, offered up Isaac: and he that
>   had received the promises offered up his only begotten son,
>
> 18 Of whom it was said, That in Isaac shall thy seed be called:
>
> 19 Accounting that God was able to raise him up, even from the dead;
>   from whence also he received him in a figure.

and given that this passage in Hebrews is specifically showing ***good*** examples of faith, to illustrate the importance of faith, it's fairly safe to say that, according to the author of Hebrews, Abraham passed the test.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't expect an explanation so far! Nice and clear.